# Need help using PSKMOD

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, communication, digital

```
M = 2; %Modulation order
imdata = imread('http://openvip.sourceforge.net/userdoc/lena_grayscale.jpg'); 
bdata = de2bi(imdata);        
sizec = size(bdata,1);         
sizer = size(bdata,2);         
nbits = sizec*sizer;            
msg = reshape(bdata,nbits,1);
txpsk = pskmod(msg,M);
```

the above code is giving the following errors.need help fixing the following errors

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Complex integer arithmetic is not supported.

Error in ==> pskmod at 101
y = exp(j*(theta + ini_phase));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the line  `msg = reshape(bdata,nbits,1)`  to `msg = double(reshape(bdata,nbits,1));`  . it will work . if you need more clarification ask me i will explain you.

Comment: can you explain why we need to use double?

Comment: whenever you read a image in matlab it will take as uint8 or uint16 as per the image.But in the pskmod function, line 101  it creating the complex number which need datatype as double for theta. that way it give error.